# scene.add(object) creates an "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined"

Tags: collada, three.js

Getting that error in my javascript console(in Chrome) with a collada object I'm attempting to add with a basic loader.  It's specifically coming from the "scene.add( object )" chunk of it.  Everything else seems to work just fine.  The code for loading the object is as follows

```
var ltable;
var furnLoad = new THREE.ColladaLoader();

function addlt(){
        furnLoad.load('../Models/Furniture/foldingLongTable.dae', function(collada){
                ltable = collada.scene;
                ltable.scale.x=ltable.scale.y=ltable.scale.z=1;
                ltable.updateMatrix();
                ltable.position.x=ltable.position.z=ltable.position.y=0;
        });
        scene.add( ltable );
}
```

This function is called during the init of a page that, otherwise, works just fine.  That page can be found [here](http://babbage.cs.missouri.edu/~cs4970sp11grp2/webgl_tests/3/)(version without this table has the same URL except for a 4 instead of a 3 at the end), and the specific object [here](http://babbage.cs.missouri.edu/~cs4970sp11grp2/webgl_tests/Models/Furniture/foldingLongTable.dae).

What would be the recommended way to get past this error?

Comment: Is there any chance that the anonymous function passed to furnLoad.load isn't called? That would cause ltable to never be set. You should try asserting the value of ltable.

Comment: potentially possible.  I just commented out the "scene.add(ltable);" and added an alert saying "if(!ltable){alert("No table")};" to see.  No alert was thrown, so I'm guessing it's getting set correctly.

Comment: Then I'm afraid you'll have to wait for someone with more knowledge about callada or javascript, as i have knowledge of neither. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RESOLVED.  Collada loaders just hate being part of any function and won't work when in them.  So the fix is to have them outside of functions and they work just fine.

Comment: What does that mean?  Do you have to run them in the global scope?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to this issue is due to the location of the `scene.add()` being outside of the callback function. It is being called before the callback fires, hence the undefined error.